# Slow Network - DidSelectRowAtIndexPath delayed

Tags: ios, performance, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a table that is refreshing itself every two seconds. **It works great on the simulator and on my wifi**. But once I switch to the cellular network (or any slow network), I cannot select the rows reliably.

Sometimes when I click a row it will work after 8 seconds. Sometimes never.

I thought my refresh function was causing the delay but I printed the time at the beginning and end of the function and it only takes 2 milliseconds.

**Has anyone had a similar slow network issue**? Any tips on what might be the cause of the hang-up?

My refresh function is called in viewDidLoad:

```
//Set timer to call refresh function every two seconds
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

My updateMethod is:

```
- (void) updateMethod
{
  [columnArray removeAllObjects];
  [self getColumnData];
  [homeTable reloadData];

}
```

getColumnData calls a website and puts data in the columnArray

Comment: does your didselectrowatindexpath calls the "refresh" function ?

Comment: I edited my question in response - it's called in viewDidLoad

Comment: Could you post 'updateMethod'

Comment: Are you performing the network operation on the main queue? If so, you must move the network operation to a background queue and only update the UI - in the main queue - upon completion/error of the network operation.

Comment: I think I am using the main queue. How do I move the network operation to the background queue?

Comment: OK. I answered below with a code sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must not perform network operations on the main queue. You can create an NSOperationQueue to move the network logic to a background queue and only perform the UI update in the main queue when the network operation ends.

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
queue.name = @"Data request queue";

[queue addOperationWithBlock:^{
   [self getColumnData];
   [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        [homeTable reloadData];
    }];
 }];
```

Comment: I'm getting a SIGABRT error when I implement your code in my 'updateMethod'. Is that where this code should go?

Comment: The error reason: *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]. I added "[columnArray removeAllObjects];" before [self getColumnData]. Was that incorrect?

Comment: Yes, you can create the queue in your updateMethod. Use zombies and create a breakpoint for all exceptions to find out about the error.

Comment: The for loop in getColumnData is no longer working quite right. The index goes: 0,1,2,3,4, 0, 5

Comment: Thanks serrgi - I found and fixed the SIGABRT issue. This code fixed the performance issue!